# How to index data in Solr from the database automatically using wget

Tags: solr, indexing, automatic-updates

how to index data in Solr from the database automatically using wget?
I found the script:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash 
> wgetProgram=wget.
> urlCmd='http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import&clean=false'
> statusCmd='http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=status'
> outputDir=/opt/aurora/solr/conf/
> $wgetProgram -O $outputDir/check_status_update_index.txt ${statusCmd}.
> 2>/dev/null.
> status=`fgrep idle $outputDir/check_status_update_index.txt`.
> if [[ ${status} == *idle* ]].
> then.
>      $wgetProgram -O $outputDir/status_update_index.txt ${urlCmd}.
> 2>/dev/null.
> fi
> ```

But it does not work

Comment: What does `does not work` mean? What are your exceptions in the log? Did it ever run? Did you change something in your dataimport config?

Answer (score 0):

IF i run:

```
wget http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=status
--2013-11-27 18:28:02--  http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=status
Распознаётся localhost... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Устанавливается соединение с localhost|::1|:8983... соединение установлено.
Запрос HTTP послан, ожидается ответ... 404 Not Found
2013-11-27 18:28:02 ОШИБКА 404: Not Found.
```

I do not know what to change in the dataimport configuration.